Ask in PowerApps missing: Power Automate
I have a PowerApp. In the PowerApp I go to power automate and select create new flow. I select create from blank. I add step to initialize variable and there is no dynamic content available. Specifically the ask in power apps I keep seeing in YouTube videos. What do I do? enter image description here

It happens some time. Try refreshing couple of times or just create a new flow.

Hm no doesn’t help. So weird. I’ve watched like 5 different YouTube videos and they all click the button then action that power automate. I don’t see that option for me. Those YouTube videos are older so maybe that’s the way it use to be done. I feel like I’m missing something. Idk.

Are you using Power Apps (V2) or PowerApps trigger in your flow? Both triggers have different options to get inputs from the app. Check below answer and let me know if you need any further help.

If you are using Power Apps (V2) trigger in your Power automate flow (which is default now a days) --> you will not get "Ask in Power Apps" option in dynamic content.
You have to define your own inputs inside trigger instead of "Ask in Power Apps" option.
Example:
Power Apps V2:

It is recommended to use Power Apps (V2) trigger in Power automate currently.

Old approach using PowerApps trigger:


Yup. Thanks! This is exactly it

You are welcome! I am glad it helped you.
